# Set date column default for specific time on day

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, date-time

I have a date and time column in a SharePoint document library

Is it possible for the default value to be a certain time (e.g. 1pm) on the day of creation?

Answer (score 0):

The default value cannot refer to other fields. So there are two options for you to achieve this:

1.Use calculated column. Calculated formula :

```
=DATE(YEAR(Created),MONTH(Created),DAY(Created))+13/24
```

2.Use workflow. Start the workflow automatically when an item is created.

[image]